# How to place custom leaflet.draw shape programmatically?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson, leaflet.draw

I'd like to restore a custom L.Draw.Marker (L.Draw.Waypoint) from database, but when i try to initialize it, the result is not a proper layer, but simply the handler. How can i do this without using my mouse to click on the Button to activate the handler and then somewhere on the map to place the Waypoint?

I was able to do something close with L.geoJson(), but that's just a normal marker without the functionality of my waypoint object...or is there a way to create a waypoint out of a GeoJSON layer?

something like this:

```
function load_shape() {
    let test_wp = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "layer_type": "waypoint",
            "map_id": 0,
            "rotation": -44
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [27.712348, 5.000000]
        }
    };
    
    let geojson = L.geoJson(test_wp); <- works
    let wp = waypoint(map, geojson._layers[geojson._leaflet_id-1]); <- works too, but this is 
                                                                       just the handler

    drawnItems.addLayer(wp.layer); <- doesn't work of course, just to get the idea...
    - or -
    wp.layer.addTo(map)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
L.geoJson(test_wp, {
            // style: function (feature) {
            //     return {color: feature.properties.color};
            // },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'static/images/icons/arrow-alt-circle-up-regular.svg',
                        iconSize: [18, 18],
                        iconAnchor: [9, 9],
                    }),
                    rotationOrigin: 'center center',
                })
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                    //open a popup or whatever
                });

                layer.on('drag', function (e) {
                    //when dragging do...
                });

                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description).addTo(drawnItems);
            }
        });
```

This doesn't create my custom marker, but i can give it all the functionality i need.